# Toolbar buttons are nor displaying in react wysiwyg froala editor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, wysiwyg, froala

I would like to know how to display toolbar buttons in react wysiwyg froala editor,
Currently editor shows only three icons(bold, italic, underline).
I have added the below config as per docs but was not working

```
this.state={
      config : {
        colorsHEXInput: false,
        autoFocus: true,
        toolbartop: true,
        linkAlwaysBlank: true,
        fontFamilySelection: true,
        fontSizeSelection: true,
        paragraphFormatSelection: true,
        htmlExecuteScripts: true,
        iframe: true,
        tabSpaces: 4,
       // pluginsEnabled: ['align', 'charCounter', 'codeBeautifier', 'codeView', 'colors', 'draggable', 'embedly', 'emoticons', 'entities', 'file', 'fontFamily', 'fontSize', 'fullscreen', 'image', 'imageManager', 'inlineStyle', 'lineBreaker', 'link', 'lists', 'paragraphFormat', 'paragraphStyle', 'quickInsert', 'quote', 'save', 'table', 'url', 'video', 'wordPaste'],
        toolbarButtons:{
          moreText: {
            buttons: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikeThrough', 'subscript', 'superscript', 'fontFamily', 'fontSize', 'textColor', 'backgroundColor', 'inlineClass', 'inlineStyle', 'clearFormatting'],

            // Alignment of the group in the toolbar.
            align: 'left',

            // By default, 3 buttons are shown in the main toolbar. The rest of them are available when using the more button.
            buttonsVisible: 3
          },


          moreParagraph: {
            buttons: ['alignLeft', 'alignCenter', 'formatOLSimple', 'alignRight', 'alignJustify', 'formatOL', 'formatUL', 'paragraphFormat', 'paragraphStyle', 'lineHeight', 'outdent', 'indent', 'quote'],
            align: 'left',
            buttonsVisible: 3
          },

          moreRich: {
            buttons: ['insertLink', 'insertImage', 'insertVideo', 'insertTable', 'emoticons', 'fontAwesome', 'specialCharacters', 'embedly', 'insertFile', 'insertHR'],
            align: 'left',
            buttonsVisible: 3
          },

          moreMisc: {
            buttons: ['undo', 'redo', 'fullscreen', 'print', 'getPDF', 'spellChecker', 'selectAll', 'html', 'help'],
            align: 'right',
            buttonsVisible: 2
          }
        }
      }
}
render(){   return (<FroalaEditor
              config = {this.state.config}
              model={this.state.emailbody}
              onModelChange={this.handleChange}
            />);}
```

Comment: I think you are missing a return statement in your `render()` method

Comment: @GaborSzekely thanks for reply, did but not dispalying

Comment: In documentation mentioned, you need to include the related plugins for toolbar options. [plugins link](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/plugins). Then only it will work. @miyavv